# What is the relation of the Erlang B and C formulas to the Erlang distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity, queueing-theory

I am confused as to whether the Erlang formulas in telecommunications are related to the Erlang distribution or whether they share the same name simply because they are coined after the same Mathematician. I know for example that the Erlang B formula deals with a system that has Poisson arrivals and Exponential departures, I'm curious as to whether Erlang distributions are explicitly applied when deriving the Erlang B formula for such a system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do not need to know the Erlang distribution to derive the Erlang B formula.

Under the Poisson arrivals and exponential service assumptions, the state of an $M/M/k/k$ (exponential arrivals, exponential service, $k$ servers, at most $k$ customers in system at any time) queueing system is a simple birth-death Markov chain with state space $\{0,1,2,\ldots,k\}$. If arrivals have rate $\lambda$ and service has rate $\mu$, the chain transitions from $i$ to $i+1$ at rate $\lambda$ ($i=0,1,\ldots,k-1$), and it transitions from $i$ to $i-1$ at rate $\mu$ ($i=1,2,\ldots,k$). With this information, you can derive the stationary distribution
\begin{align*}
\pi_i = \frac{(\lambda/\mu)^i/i!}{\sum_{j=0}^k (\lambda/\mu)^j/j!}, \quad i=0,1,2\ldots,k. \quad (\ast)
\end{align*}
You can also derive this distribution by first finding the stationary distribution for an $M/M/\infty/\infty$ system (infinitely many servers); the state space in that case is $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, the stationary distribution is $\pi_i = e^{-\lambda}(\lambda/\mu)^i/i!$ (Poisson distribution), and you can get $(\ast)$ by reducing the state space to $\{0,1,2,\ldots,k\}$ and renormalizing the distribution.

Anyway, once you know the stationary distribution in $(\ast)$, you can derive the Erlang formula by using the PASTA property (Poisson arrivals see time averages). This property means that the probability that a Poisson arrival finds the system in state $i$ is $\pi_i$. So the probability that a Poisson arrival arrives to a full system is
$$
\pi_k = \frac{(\lambda/\mu)^k/k!}{\sum_{j=0}^k (\lambda/\mu)^j/j!},
$$
i.e. the long-run probability that there are $k$ customers in the system.

Summary: The Erlang B formula only requires knowledge of how to obtain stationary distributions for simple birth-death Markov chains and knowledge of the PASTA property. You do not need to know anything about the Erlang distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still slightly confused as to the relation between the Erlang distribution and the Erlang B and C formulas. I've been asked as an assignment to discuss the Erlang distribution and its relationship to queueing theory, are the Erlang formulas then a completely separate thing? Or are they relevant enough to the Erlang distribution for me to discuss them in the context of my topic?

Comment: I think you should think about the Erlang distribution on its own rather than tying it to Erlang B/C, since it is used in different contexts. For example, in a queueing system where customers have to be served by $k$ agents consecutively, each with service rate $\mu$, their service time is Erlang-($k$,$\mu$) (not including any queueing time). I don't know the topics of the class you're in, but the Erlang distribution can also be used to approximate more complicated arrival-time and service-time distributions.

Comment: Another situation where the Erlang distribution is useful: If you arrive to a single-server system with service at rate $\mu$, and you find $k$ people ahead of you in the queue (not including the person in service), the time you have to wait in the queue is Erlang-$(k+1,\mu)$.

Comment: These are pretty helpful examples, I'll be sure to expand on them. Thanks! If I can bother you with just one more question, which you are free to ignore, I was told by my instructor to touch convolution and he informed me that I should discover that convolution and the Erlang dist are related, the only way I can find so far is that Convolution is used to get the dist of a RV that is the sum of independent RVs. This is the case between Erlang and exp distributions, is there a more major link I'm missing?

Comment: No I think you're right, the Erlang distribution is just a particular convolution involving exponentials.